# Linking to Css file in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, url-rewriting

So today I started using code-igniter and I have come across a problem.
The problem is that I want to link a css file to my default view. My attempt was to put my css file in the root in root. So it looks like this

```
-Root
--application
--system
--styles
----main.css
--index.php
```

Then in my view I link my css file by pretending it was in the same folder like this:

```
<link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Now when I access my default controler like this: `http://localhost/index.php` it works!!
But when I access it like this `http://localhost/index.php/home/index` it doesn't work. it tries to access the css file using this path `http://localhost/index.php/styles/main.css`

**How do i fix this or moreover, what is the right way to do this?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226706/placing-of-css-in-codeigniter-views/10254723#10254723  You might want to read that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url() ?>styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

if you are using codeigniter version lower than 2.0 you must specify `base_url` in `config.php`

...

or you can specify the base tag

```
<base href="<?php echo base_url()?>">
```

and all your relative paths will be prefixed by `base_url`

it works only in current view (I prefer add it to template view)

...

or check [this](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Asset-Helper)

Comment: do I have to do this every time, like say I have a folder images also. now whenever I link images using the `<img />` tag. It will really look bad every time i call base_url(). Ism't there an alternative such as adding a route? or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

user base_url() instead of site_url()

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('styles/main.css')?>" />
```

Define your base_url() in your config.php file

Answer (score 0):

As Maarty answered, you should use:

`<link href="<?php echo base_url() ?>styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

As for your second questions as to whether you have to do this everytime, check out [Comper Template Parser](http://parser.comper.sk/en/), it's pretty good and extremely easy to setup. It creates pseudo variables out of your data variables -- What I do is add a styles, javascript and whatever else variable inside the Parser file, for example something like:

```
array('styles' => base_url() . '/stylesheets/',
      'scripts' => base_url() . '/javascripts/',
      'something' => base_url() . '/something-awesome/');
```

Would allow you do put this in your template file:

```
<link href="{styles}/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="{styles}/other.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="{scripts}/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="{scripts}/amazing.js"></script>

<img src="{something}/something.jpg"/>
```

Do yourself a favour and checkout [Comper Template Parser](http://parser.comper.sk/en/) -- it's a real treat.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you already kept your 
    $config['base_url']= 'http://www.yourproject.com/';

in the application/config/config.php line number 17

So you need to use 'base_url' in  your view files. such as for css ::::

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

It will be work in your project. Thanks