# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) including css files and js libraries

Tags: html, codeigniter, permissions, localhost, easyphp

I'm starting developing with codeigniter and I'm doing some few basically things to learn it on localhost with easyphp (I get bug with WAMP Server).

I create the folder "libraries/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js", and "views/templates/css/style.css" and simply in header I include the files:

```
<link type="text/css" href="application/views/templates/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="application/libraries/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
```

And the server return to me the follow errors:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8887/CodeIgniter_2.1.3/application/libraries/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js 403 (Forbidden)
GET http://127.0.0.1:8887/CodeIgniter_2.1.3/application/views/tamplates/css/style.css 403 (Forbidden)
```

I searched for info and can be a permission problem in the files, but never happened to me before... and in a remote server I can access by ftp and change the permission, but how can I do it on localhost? If thats the problem..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you use WAMP, I can safely assume that you are on Windows?

Comment: @ruudy - take a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397512/codeigniter-not-reading-jquery/14397725#14397725) and do the same for your css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found a solution here:

[Where do I put image files, css, js, etc. in Codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630770/where-do-i-put-image-files-css-etc-in-code-igniter)

All people put those kind of files outside the codeigniter framework, i make it and now it works.

Thanks for the help.

PD: Now im fighting with the helper creation :D

Answer (score 0):

A little Googling would probably suffice: [How to set, view, change, or remove special permissions for files and folders in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308419).

Comment: But im not sure is that is the problem...it is?

Comment: Well just try it and see if it works, no one here can debug your problem for you!

Comment: That files already have modify, read and execute, read and write permissions for users, authentify users, systema and administrator :S. I want to know why this error is caused. Thanks.

Comment: Check your .htaccess file. Also make sure that permissions for files are set to 644 and folder are set to 755.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using macOS just right click on the folders in which your js and css files lie then click get info and tick the shared folder checkbox.