# Style CSS does not With CodeIgniter - Baseurl

Tags: css, image, codeigniter, base-url

This question has been asked several times, but have not found the right answer which will work on my project.

my CSS file liking

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css"/>
```

The css file is in:

```
-main_directory
  -Application
  -Assets
    -css
       -style.css
  -System
```

I also tried to link css using base_url `href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/style.css');?>"` but it doesn't work for me.

So what is the problem? Can anyone help?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630770/where-do-i-put-image-files-css-etc-in-code-igniter

Comment: have u loaded url helper?

Comment: make your practice to accept answer if you think some answer is useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your structure should be like this

```
myproject
  application
  assets
    css
       style.css
 system
```

autoload url helper in `config/autoload.php`

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Now

```
<link href = '<?php echo base_url()?>/assets/css/style.css'>
```

This should work. Make sure your spellings are correct and see the casd sensitive issue if you are using linux.

Answer (score 1):

is your base_url() method config properly? Check here...

```
ci_app_folder/config/config.php
```

if yours is located in c:/xampp/htdocs/ci_app_name

```
$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/ci_app_name'; //or localhost:90/ci_app_name if you had changed port
```

Then you can use this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/style.css'); ?>" >
```

You can also set base_url() empty . If you haven't uploaded to web hosting/server.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this once -
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/style.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could place the custom css links like this :

```
    background-image:url(../../); moving back to the directory you want
```

using CI you need to use in-line css: eg.

```
    <div style = background-image: url(<?php echo base_url();?>)assets/images/>
    </div>
```