# My css page is not loadin in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

In *constants.php* I have

```
define('URL','localhost/indianeers/');
define('CSS',URL.'assets/css/');
```

and *config.php* I have

```
 $config['base_url']= URL;
```

and view page I attached

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo CSS.'developer.css' ;?>" />
```

But this page is not loaded it seems page not found. Can anyone help me please.

Comment: Where are your css files located ?

Comment: my project folder/assets/css/develope.css

Comment: if you go directly to **`http://localhost/indianeers/assets/css/develope.css`**, is it loading the css file ?

Comment: It is showing 404 error ...

Comment: are you sure the file is there ? Can you attach you **`.htaccess`** with your question ?

Comment: this is code i put in my .htaccess     RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: Replace this and with your **`.htaccess`** and try..
**`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>`**

Comment: I'll update it as the answer then :)

Comment: chumma i said !! i didnt test ur code !! before that i only corrected .htaccess my self as RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: with your method you have to add the excluded folders each time in the **`.htaccess`**, That is why I suggested the other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your file **`assets/css/developer.css`** is available and You can not access it directly via

**`http://localhost/indianeers/assets/css/develope.css`**

then the problem is with your **`.htaccess`**. Replace it with the following,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$config['base_url']= URL;
```

to

```
$config['base_url']= "http://localhost/indianeers/"
```

and use `base_url` function, no need to use constant

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/developer.css') ;?>" />
```

OR if you can load `html` helper then [**`link_tag()`**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/html_helper.html#link_tag) function for load css

Comment: it is not working .Actually where shoud i keep my css files .

Comment: to manage your public assets, follow this, http://stackoverflow.com/a/22412426/567854, structure.

Comment: in /root dir  => css folder

Comment: it is not working ..first of all i didnt see this tag <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/developer.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> while inspecting with bugzilla

Answer (score 0):

U can also use **Base Tag** in `Html` (View) `Head`

Create a folder named **assets** in root directory of your project and create **css** folder in it then Place you css there `rootdir(project name)/assets/css/developer.css`

```
<head>
    <base href="<?php echo base_url()?>" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/developer.css" />
</head>
```

Comment: no yar !! i used same !! but if i am putting  <base href="<?php echo base_url() ;?>" /> my <link href tag is not displaying