# Code Igniter - http://localhost:8081/ci/assets/js/jquery.js%22 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: codeigniter

I searched other posts and tried creating a helper function to create an asset_url as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630770/where-do-i-put-image-files-css-js-etc-in-codeigniter), but no luck. I previously had to set the base site in my config.php file as such: `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8081/ci';`.

The code in my application\views\layouts\main.php file, just before the closing body tag is:

`<script src=<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src=<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

I'm running on XAMPP. I had to change the port number to 8081 after installing visual stuido and it conflicted with the default port 80. So my exact queston is what else can I do to resolve the 403 forbidden access in code igniter so that JS and Jquery scripts will work?

Comment: Seems like you have restricted its access in your .htaccess file

Comment: Put `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` at the end: `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8081/ci/';`. You forgot opening double quotes for `src`.

Comment: Thank you! Scripts work now.